# Sorting list of dicts in order of values

Tags: python, list, sorting

How can i do this:

> In:

```
a = [{'10100': u'Z'}, {u'00101': u'C'}, {u'01100': u'B'}, {u'00111': u'T'}]
```

> Out:

```
a = [{u'01100': u'B'}, {u'00101': u'C'}, {u'00111': u'T'}, {'10100': u'Z'}]
```

I mean in order to value

Comment: Why `dict`s instead of `tuple`s? ex. `{'10100': u'Z'}` -> `('10100', u'Z')`

Comment: Can you post the code that you've tried thus far?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-values-of-the-dictionary-in-python

Comment: `sorted(a, key=lambda k: k.values())`

Comment: @Stack Nah, that one has a shared key by which to compare. This one doesn't.

Comment: @davedwards `sorted(a, key=dict.values)`

Comment: Just use `tuple` objects... `dict` doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dict.values()` in the sorting key:

```
a = [{'10100': u'Z'}, {u'00101': u'C'}, {u'01100': u'B'}, {u'00111': u'T'}]
new_a = sorted(a, key=lambda x:x.values()[0])
```

Output:

```
[{u'01100': u'B'}, {u'00101': u'C'}, {u'00111': u'T'}, {'10100': u'Z'}]
```